# How did J. M. Barrie come up with the names for the Lost Boys?

Tags: peter-pan, j-m-barrie

In *Peter Pan*, four of the six Lost Boys are named: Tootles, Nibs, Curly, and Slightly. How did Barrie come up with these names? Were they common nicknames at the time the play was written? "Curly" obviously seems to still be in contemporary use, but the other three sound strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly's name comes from what was written on his pinafore when he was "Lost" as a baby:

> TOOTLES. I am awfully anxious about Cinderella. You see, not knowing anything about my own mother I am fond of thinking that she was rather like Cinderella.
>
> *(This is received with derision.)*
>
> NIBS. All I remember about my mother is that she often said to father, 'Oh how I wish I had a cheque book of my own.' I don't know what a cheque book is, but I should just love to give my mother one.
>
> SLIGHTLY *(as usual)*. My mother was fonder of me than your mothers were of you. *(Uproar.)* Oh yes, she was. Peter had to make up names for you, but my mother had wrote my name on the pinafore I was lost in. 'Slightly Soiled'; that's my name.
>
> -- [*Peter Pan* (play), 1904](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0300081h.html)

I don't think there's any canonical source on where the others' names come from. One may assume that Curly's name comes from him having had curly hair, but Tootles and Nibs are a bit more obscure.

Comment: Tootles could be a references to the English interjection meaning goodbye - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toodles#English.  Nibs could be a reference to "his nibs" a somewhat derisive term for an authority figure - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/His+Nibs.  No evidence of course hence just a comment.

Comment: @EricNolan Ooh, I didn't think about "his nibs". I did think of toodles/Tootles, but couldn't figure out an argument for how it'd make sense as the name of a person.

Comment: Tootles could be an endearment for 'one who passes gas'

Comment: The Etymologicon goes into the source for the names Wendy and Neverland but not those of the Lost Boy's unfortunately.  https://books.google.ca/books?id=U0zav6EgOwYC&pg=PT175&lpg=PT175&dq=Peter+Pan+Barrie+Etymologicon&source=bl&ots=RDfnPgTeGM&sig=ACfU3U3tPdNH8yvppnRe5tMJGxzbeTOV4g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-mNGP49rwAhXmMlkFHcc6DZ4Q6AEwEHoECB0QAw#v=onepage&q=Peter%20Pan%20Barrie%20Etymologicon&f=false

Comment: @RandAl'Thor it's Peter doing the naming, and he doesn't really understand names (hence thinking "Slightly Soiled" is a person's name).  I think all the names are intentionally (from a writerly perspective) off